# Перехват исключения при делении на 0

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь отловить исключение через catch/try:

```
void TestCall()
{
    int b=0;
    try
    {

        int a = 1/b;        
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        test(1);
    }
}
```

Выражение `int a = 1/b;` заведомо вызывает исключение деления на 0 и я хоч его поймать в блоке catch. Но Visual C++ упорно вызывает ошибку на нем и на catch не перекидывает. В чем секрет?

Comment: Ну есть __try/__catch но это только для VS. Но лучше наверное хендлер настроить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы путаете исключения С++ и прочие исключения. В С++ исключения возникают исключительно при использовании оператора `throw`. Деление на 0 при использовании встроенного оператора `/` является неопределенным поведением:

> **8.6 Multiplicative operators [expr.mul]**
>
> 4 The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Ориентировался на примеры из интернета. Например, у автора статьи https://habr.com/sandbox/28877/ почему-то заработал...

Comment: @Александр Эта статья валяется в песочнице явно не просто так. Автор использовал скользкое выражение "перехват системного исключения" - такой код мог бы работать в VS при включении нестандартного [расширения для обработки SEH](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp).

Answer (score 2):

В Windows деление на ноль генерирует исключение SEH с кодом *STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO* (0xC0000094). Чтобы обрабатывать его в стиле исключений С++, можно установить в Visual C++ параметр компилятора [/EHa](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model), или установить фильтр необработанных исключений:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <exception>
#include <windows.h>

LONG WINAPI UnhandledExceptionFilter( struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *ExceptionInfo){

    if(ExceptionInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO)
        throw std::exception("STATUS_INTEGER_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO");  

    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(&UnhandledExceptionFilter); 

    int b=0;
    try
    {
        int a = 1/b;        
    }
    catch(std::exception ex)
    {       
        printf("Exception: %s\n",ex.what());
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

(Второй способ работает только при запуске без отладки, так как отладчик студии принудительно прерывает программу на SEH-исключениях.)

Comment: В visual c++ понятно. А если gcc/mingw?

Comment: @Александр Под Windows, способ с SetUnhandledExceptionFilter должен работать в любом компиляторе. Под другие ОС - не знаю.