# Может ли поток упасть без обрушения процесса?

Tags: c++, многопоточность, процесс

Может ли возникнуть такая ситуация, что поток в процессе падает или зависает из-за ошибки (ошибка сегментации, деление на ноль, повреждение памяти, состояние гонки и пр.), но при этом процесс с таким потоком внутри продолжает работать?

Если да, то когда возможна такая ситуация?

Comment: не представил как может  доставка  приостановлена, а процесс доставки продолжен

Comment: на вряд ли, так как если потоки относятся к одному процессу то логично чтобы все рушилось вместе, если не перехвачена ошибка, мало ли что это деление на ноль может повлечь за собой, например смерть человека, и лучше чтобы человек предусмотрел все исключительные случаи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В С++, с точки зрения стандарта, нет понятия "падает или зависает" - перечисленные состояния приводят к неопределенному поведению. Например, для деления на ноль это описано в разделе 8.6 Multiplicative operators, пункт 4:

> If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undeﬁned.

Неопределенное поведение означает, что стандарт не накладывает ограничений на поведение программы, и реализация не обязана его документировать. В случае целочисленного деления на ноль, однако, поведение в большинстве реализаций хорошо известно: вся программа аварийно завершается при попытке деления на ноль в любом потоке. Более того, в Windows известны также используемые при этом коды SEH-исключений, что позволяет отреагировать на эту ситуацию и продолжить выполнение программы, в том числе и в том же потоке. Как это сделать, описано здесь: [Перехват исключения при делении на 0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/842745/240512)

То же самое применимо к большинству других ошибочных ситуаций, кроме состояния гонки, так как оно обычно приводит не к аварийному завершению, а просто к считыванию/записи плохих данных. То есть на "Может ли поток упасть без обрушения процесса?" ответ - "теоретически да, смотря что понимать под падением". Но на практике стоит рассчитывать на то, что такие ошибки приведут к аварийному завершению всего процесса.

Answer (score 0):

Ситуация типичная в многопоточном приложении.

Каждый поток отдельный класс как и процесс. С чего должна рушиться программа если скажем поток передачи данных упал?

Браузер обновляет страницу ошибка передачи данных, деление на ноль, страница не загрузилась Браузер работает дальше.

Вы пытаетесь считать и обработать файл другим потоком, поток умер не справился. как это должно влиять?

Comment: Браузер не показатель, интерпретатор Javascript может проверять аргументы перед выполнением деления, да и вкладки могут быть вынесены в отдельный процесс.